# Impossible to surf on some web sites after some time

Tags: networking, browser

I am fighting with a difficult problem with my internet connection.

When I am connected to internet, after some time (about half an hour), some sites suddenly are no longer accessible. But not all sites! For example, if I'm watching videos on YouTube or browsing Facebook, I can go on surfing on those sites without problems. But if I try to visit a different site, on which I was not surfing previously (eg. Twitter), here I get an error (i.e. CONNECTION REFUSED on Chrome).

In more details:

1. it happens after some time of regular surfing
2. it occurs on all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Ie) and on all PCs and tablets connected on my LAN, cable or wifi
3. it happens on Windows 7, on Windows 10 and on Android
4. If I am already visiting a site (that is, for example, I am already on YouTube), I can continue to do so without any problem, but I can not surf other sites that I had not opened before the problem occurred
5. However, if I close the browser and reopen it, I can not even browse these sites that were previously accessible
6. if I use a proxy with Epic Browser, I can continue to surf everywhere (in fact it is what I am doing at the moment)

I called my provider (Wind-Infostrada) and they resetted the connection and changed the DNS and IP addresses, to no avail. My router is a SITECOM WLM 4500.

I also tried the troubleshooting wizard on Windows and I got the message "the device or remote resource does not accept the connection" without solving anything.
Before rushing out to buy a new router, I'd like to get an idea of ​​why it happens. Does anyone have a theory about it?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Change router. Ask a friend if he's got a spare. I mean, if you replaced the DNS IP on every client and this continues, it must be the router. (Well "must be" is a brave term in IT, but that thing is my prime suspect here.)

Comment: @Shiki Or he could reset the router to factory settings, or try reflashing the router.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I also think that the problem is in the router, but I am not able to figure out what kind of problem it could be. In which way it could happen that, after some surfing, some web sites become inaccessible while other ones continue working?
I believe it could be a problem of DNS. But I tried (with no results) this:

1) change DNS on my PC's
2) using direct IP address to access a web site while internet is blocked

Notice that the problem is happening not only with browser surfing, but also with other programs using internet connection on my PC.

Thank a lot!

Comment: Routers can go haywire for no reason. They are cheap for a reason. My friend bought a cheaper TP-Link router - it was not even the cheapest model - and it just randomly drops the wifi + wan. After hours, days, it's totally random. **Again, try what oldmud said, reset, reflash router. If problem persists, try things with a different router.**